# perform math operation between scalar and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In an existing code, I used the following code to perform operation against a dataframe column.

```
df.loc[:, ['test1']] = m/(df.loc[:, ['rh']]*d1)
```

Here, both `m` and `d1` are scalar. 'test1' and 'rh' are the column names.

Is this the right way or the best practice to perform math operation against the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have there is fine. If you're looking for ways to improve it, a couple suggestions:

- When accessing entire columns (like you're doing here), you can be more concise by not using `.loc`, and just doing `df["test1"]` and `df["rh"]`
- You could alternatively use the `.apply()` method, which is useful for a more general case of wanting to perform any arbitrary operation (that you can implement in a function, anyway) on a DataFrame column. You *could* use it here, and it would look like
  `df["test1"] = df["rh"].apply(lambda rh: m/(rh*d1))`, though it is almost certainly not necessary for this simple case.

Comment: @Lotad, thank you for the reply. Another minor question related to this case is that, when we try to call the column name represented as a string, whether we should use "" or ' ' ? Thanks.

Comment: Makes no difference, functionally. In some specific cases, there is an official recommendation one way or the other, like [using double quotes for docstrings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/), but generally, it's a purely stylistic choice. I personally prefer double quotes in general, since it means your strings can contain apostrophes without having to escape them (i.e. you can just write the string `"haven't"`, instead of needing to do `'haven\'t'`). But it's really up to you and what you're used to.